# Android ADB over WiFi disconnects when USB cable is unplugged

Tags: android, tcp, adb

I have a Blackberry Priv (STV100-1) running Android 6.0.1 (non rooted), with USB debugging enabled.
The smartphone and the PC are both connected to the same router (the Priv's only numerical IP address under "About phone - Status" is 192.168.1.113).
I use the Command Prompt (Run as Administrator) and run the ADB server from AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools *adb start-server*.

1) If the smarphone is **not connected** to the PC through USB:

```
adb devices -l
% List of devices attached
% (empty)

ping -t 192.168.1.113
% Pinging 192.168.1.113 with 32 bytes of data:
% Reply from 192.168.1.113: bytes=32 time=297ms TTL=64
```

2) When I plug the smartphone to the PC **through USB** (PTP mode (photo transfer)):

```
adb devices -l
% List of devices attached
% 1162139011             device product:venicena model:STV100_1 device:venice

adb tcpip 5555
% restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

adb connect 192.168.1.113:5555
% connected to 192.168.1.113:5555

adb devices -l
% List of devices attached
% 192.168.1.113:5555     device product:venicena model:STV100_1 device:venice
% 1162139011             device product:venicena model:STV100_1 device:venice

ping -t 192.168.1.113
% Pinging 192.168.1.113 with 32 bytes of data:
% Reply from 192.168.1.113: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=64
```

3) When I **disconnect the smartphone** from the USB connection to the PC:

```
adb devices -l
% List of devices attached
% (empty)

ping -t 192.168.1.113
% Pinging 192.168.1.113 with 32 bytes of data:
% Reply from 192.168.1.113: bytes=32 time=266ms TTL=64
```

If I *adb kill-server* and restart the process, there is no change.
If I *adb connect 192.168.1.113*, there is no change.
If I connect the smartphone to the PC through USB in MTP mode (file transfer), there is no change.
If I use Pedro's *Android WiFi ADB - IntelliJ/Android Studio Plugin* (https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB), there is no change.

What am I doing wrong?? Is there any Windows Firewall / Router configuration I need to change??

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51904546/614026 this solved my problem