# ADB over WiFi connection is lost after disconnecting USB

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I was trying to run ADB over wifi following answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi), and I connect successfully to the device, but I lose connection after disconnecting the USB. The same result with both manual and plugins ways.
Also, I have tried [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/LKW62Xat72M) solution, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105706/adb-connection-by-wifi-getting-killed-when-a-new-usb-attached-detached) one, but without success.

Solutions that require the device is rooted won't work for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For some reason, connecting the device in **Charge only** mode solved the problem. Just make sure "**Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode**" is enabled before connecting the device.

Other modes caused the connection to be lost, as I have tested on my device running on Android 8.0.0.

Comment: Thats not true i guess. Mode is device dependent . mostly it works in  media mode for some devices in charge mode .

Comment: Are you talking about the last line? If so, it is for the sack of logging of what happened on my device, I'm not making assumptions that "Charge only" mode only would work for all devices running on Android 8.0 and other modes won't. It is obvious.

Comment: My phone is 8.0 too. It worked well. Helps me a lot. Thx.